# Sitecore 9.0.1 Custom form field element is not saving

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have created a custom hidden field element in sitecore 9.0.1 forms(refered sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html).

I have created a form and added Default form save action. While posting form data to database,the custom field is not saved in database (note: others fields are saved).

Is there anything that I missed ?

Comment: Can you paste into your question more details about implementation? Maybe somebody will find some typo or some other mistake somewhere. This is too general specification of problem as it's working for other similar custom fields as you have mentioned.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved with these below steps :

Two things we need to do to save a custom field.

1. Inherit **Save settings** template to your custom field template.

[image]

2. Navigate to your field item in question (like /sitecore/Forms/your form/page/your field) in content editor and make sure that "Allow Save" option is checked.